# Como selecionar uma opção no select de maneira menos trabalhosa?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, html-select, html-option

Tenho uma página chamada *`editarpublicacao.php`* que recebe o `id` através de `GET`.

Um dos dois `<select>` por exemplo contidos na página, é semelhante a esse, o das empresas:

```
<select name="company" data-placeholder="Selecione" class="form-control chosen-select" id="cmbCompany" required data-parsley-errors-container="#company-errors">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Selecione</option>
  <?php 
  $companies = $searchSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($companies as $empresas):
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $empresas['id_Company'];?>"><?php echo $empresas['razaoSocial']; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

E eu mostro todas as empresas através do `PHP` usando o `while` nesse .

Mas por exemplo, se eu receber no `$_GET['id']`, um `id` de valor 12,

#### Como mostrar todas empresas e selecionar uma delas? Num caso exemplo, a de id == 12, tem que estar automaticamente selecionada.

Se a de id == 12 fosse a do fulano, tinha que mostrar todas empresas e deixar selecionada a do fulano, que nem nesse snippet que eu fiz:

```html
<select name="select">
  <option value="valor1">Valor</option> 
  <option value="valor2" selected>Fulano</option>
  <option value="valor3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
```

Tenho a query que seleciona todas empresas:

```
$searchSQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_Company, razaoSocial FROM tbl_company ORDER by razaoSocial ASC");
$searchSQL->execute();
```

Como fazer isso, de mostrar todas empresas e selecionar uma delas, que tiver o id igual ao do recebido pelo $_GET?

---

Eu vi nesse [link][1] que posso fazer assim:

```
<option value="January"<?=$row['month'] == 'January' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>January</option>
```

Aí tem problemas de fazer assim, e se eu tivesse 1000 registros? Não existe uma maneira mais fácil de fazer? E como eu posso fazer?

Comment: Vc quer que retorne do banco somente 1 empresa, por exemplo, a de id valor 12?

Comment: Não @Dvdsamm quero que retorne todas as empresas, mas uma delas a de id == 12, tem que estar selecionada.

Comment: Entendi. A forme que vc citou na pergunta funciona, mas a sua preocupação é se houver muitos registros, ficando um select enorme.

Comment: Então daquele jeito eu não quero, não existe uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso? Viu a edição que fiz, melhorou?

Comment: A maneira mais simples é igual a que vc colocou na pergunta: `<option value="<?php echo $empresas['id_Company'];?>"<?=$empresas['id_Company'] == '$_GET['id']' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $empresas['razaoSocial']; ?></option>`. Entendi que sua preocupação é porque desta forma o `<select>` vai ter `<option>` demais. Neste caso, acho que um campo de texto comum que busque uma empresa dinamicamente ao digitar seu nome (ou parte dele) seja viável.

Comment: Não pode ser campo de texto, porque é uma página de edição e tem que ser um select que mostre todas empresas e selecione automaticamente a empresa com id == $_GET.

Comment: Então não vejo outra forma senão a que mostrei no último comentário.

Comment: Sim também, acredito que não tenha @Dvdsamm

Comment: Mesmo que fizesse diferente, de qualquer forma teria que puxar TODAS as 1000 empresas do banco. Seria trocar 6 por meia-dúzia.

Comment: O que vc poderia fazer, pra onerar menos o banco de dados, era puxar apenas o registro com o ID e colocar no <select>. Caso a empresa tenha que ser alterada, quando a pessoa clicar no <select> para ver as opções, aí sim puxava todos os outros registros via Ajax. Isso pode ser interessante porque, além de poupar o banco de dados puxando um grande número de registros toda vez que abrir a página, nem sempre a empresa será alterada ao editar os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso pode resolver seu problema, vai deixar como selected aquele que tiver o ID igual ao id do GET

```
<select name="company" data-placeholder="Selecione" class="form-control chosen-select" id="cmbCompany" required data-parsley-errors-container="#company-errors">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Selecione</option>
  <?php 
  $companies = $searchSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($companies as $empresas):
  if($empresas['id_Company'] == $_GET['id']){
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $empresas['id_Company'];?>" selected><?php echo $empresas['razaoSocial']; ?></option>
  <?}else{ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $empresas['id_Company'];?>"><?php echo $empresas['razaoSocial']; ?></option>
  <?}?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```